# Cannot increment object latest value in using django

Tags: python, django, oracle, increment

I want to increment the value of the last id in the table so I could enter distinct values on the next rows. I'm using oracle 11g database for my python project. Please see my sample code...

```
custID = Customer.objects.lates('CUSTOMER_ID')
custID = int(custID) + 1 #received error
custName = "Peter"

Customer.objects.create('CUSTOMER_ID'=str(custID), 'CUSTOMER_NAME'=custName) #this line is ok
```

and I got this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Customer'`

I tried to search online and changed my code like

```
Customer.objects.create('CUSTOMER_NAME'=custName)
```

but didn't worked because my it is not auto incremented on my database and python model.

I also tried this..

```
custID = sum(int(custID), 1)
```

Sorry, I'm just new in django.

Comment: Can you try to print the type of the returned custID using `type(custID)` ?

Comment: it shows `<class 'sample.models.Customer'>`

Comment: You got the error. You cannot convert a class type to an int explicitly. You need to use `custID.id` to get your id then increment it. Look at the answers below.

Comment: A side note, you should consider using `F() expressions` to avoid race conditions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand you correctly, here is your problem:

```
custID = Customer.objects.latest('CUSTOMER_ID')
```

This statement will return a `Customer` object, so you need to use

```
custId = custID.CUSTOMER_ID + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Customer.objects.latest('CUSTOMER_ID')` returns an object, not an id. What you want is this:

```
custID = Customer.objects.latest('CUSTOMER_ID').id
```

However, you shouldn't need to specify the id when creating a new customer; normally Django picks up the id itself.